# Software that sees which programs uses the internet?

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-monitoring

Is there an easy-to-use and hopefully free software that can show the user which of the running processes are connecting to the internet and how much of the bandwidth it's using?

Comment: Without knowing what OS you are using that is a impossible question to answer. Also software recommendations are not on topic as they can easily become out of date and no longer relevant. Also did you attempt to Google "[Bandwidth monitor](https://www.google.com/search?q=bandwidth+monitor)" their appears to be some promising results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Windows then follow these steps:

1. click Start Menu and in "Search programs and files" text box enter "resource" and press ENTER
2. Resource Monitor will start, click "Network" tab

There you have listed all processes that are using your bandwidth.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

On GNU/Linux:

```
sudo lsof -i
```

lists all the open connections/ports (no bandwidth).

On MS Windows, try Mike Russinovich's [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).